# If I have a matrix in the form $Ax=B$, why must I have $\begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix}=β\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\end{bmatrix}?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have inserted numbers in place of i and j, and have successfully deduced the value of β as a coefficient. However, i am unsure why we must have that equation if we know $A\begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix}=0$.

Comment: This question is very unclear - it in not clear what your vectors have to do with $Ax=B.$ What do you mean "you must have?"

Comment: If  "$A\begin{bmatrix} i \\ j\end{bmatrix}= 0$" **and** "$Ax= B$" then $A\left(x+ \beta \begin{bmatrix} i \\ j\end{bmatrix}\right)= Ax+ \beta A\begin{bmatrix} i \\ j \end{bmatrix}= B$ for any $\beta$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes thank you, sorry for the poor wording